# AES decryption with bouncy castle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I am attempting to adapt the sample code at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm to have to be invoked with 3 arguments, the mode (encryption or decryption), IV and the key. It also reads and writes to specific files.

As of right now I am ignoring the given IV and key until I get the rest up and running. My code successfully encrypts plaintext from a file, and writes the ciphertext to a file, but the decryption does not work. It appears that decryption mode reads in more bytes than encryption wrote and I get block alignment errors.

I'm sure there is some fundamental error somewhere in the decryption section but I do not know what it is.  If anyone can identify the issue or can see any blatant errors that may cause it please let me know.

The error occurs at the

```
try{ ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);}catch{IllegalBlockSizeException e)
```

line of code in:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.ShortBufferException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;



@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AESCTR {
    static String inputFile = "plain-in.txt";
    static String outputFile = "cipher-out.txt";
    static String cInputFile = "cipher-in.txt";
    static String cOutputFile = "plain-out.txt";
    static String mode;
    static String IV;
    static String key;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null){
            System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is NOT available");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is available");
        } 
        Security.addProvider(Security.getProvider("BC")); 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args.length != 3){
            System.out.println("Invalid number of arguments\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        mode = args[0];
        IV = args[1];
        key = args[2];
        if ((!mode.equals("enc")) && (!mode.equals("dec"))){
            System.out.println("Invalid mode\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};
        System.out.println(keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        System.out.println("Mode: " + mode + " IV: " + IV + " Key: " + key);
        if(mode.equals("enc")){
            int ctLength = 0;
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                Path path = Paths.get(inputFile);
                data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Invalid Path\n");
                System.exit(-1);
             }
            while((data.length % 16) != 0){ //Padding
                byte[] dest = new byte[data.length + 1];
                byte[] pad = new byte[] {0x00};
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, dest, 0, data.length);
                System.arraycopy(pad, 0, dest, data.length, pad.length);    
                data = dest;
            }
            System.out.println(data.length);
            byte[] cipherText = new byte[data.length];

            Cipher cipher = null;
            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("input text : " + new String(data));

            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ctLength = cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, cipherText, 0);    
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Writer writer = null;
            try{ writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new     FileOutputStream(cInputFile), "utf-8"));
            writer.write(new String(cipherText));
            } catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("File Write Error\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            } finally{
                try{writer.close();}catch (Exception ex){}
            }

            byte[] c = null;
            try {
                Path path = Paths.get(cInputFile);
                c = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Invalid Path\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            System.out.println("cipher text: " + new String(c) + " bytes: " + ctLength);
        }
        else if (mode.equals("dec")){
            byte[] c = null;
            try {
                Path path = Paths.get(cInputFile);
                c = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                File f = new File(cInputFile);
                System.out.println("In Bytes: " + c.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Invalid Path\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            Cipher cipher = null;
            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] plainText = new byte[c.length];
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int ptLength = 0;
            try {
                ptLength = cipher.update(c, 0, c.length, plainText, 0);
                System.out.println(ptLength);
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("plain text : " + new String(plainText) + " bytes: " + ptLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact exception and where is it thrown? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: The error occurs at the try{ ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);}catch{IllegalBlockSizeException e) @Artjom B.

Comment: That encryption example is so basic that it is both not secure nor correct. The mistake of showing the ciphertext as string is already present in the "example". Don't give any trust to random code samples on the internet, *especially* when crypto is involved.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for the advice,  I'd give you an upvote but I think my rank on here is too low to do so.

Comment: I got just enough rep from this to upvote so I went back and did @MaartenBodewes

Comment: OK, thanks. Note that I don't even remember why I posted that comment; both ECB *and* CTR are readily available in Java SE (`"AES/CTR/NoPadding"`). The example you pointed at used Bouncy Castle for some reason or other. That doesn't mean that it isn't good practice to try and implement it yourself of course.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes my ultimate goal is to implement AES in both CTR and CBC mode, largely by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to decode a lot of random bytes as UTF-8 encoded text. That won't work. Your cipher text becomes corrupted, because any byte sequences that don't form a valid UTF-8 encoding of a character will be replaced with the replacement character, 0+FFFD (�).

Cipher text is not actually text. Don't use APIs like `Writer` and `Reader` that work with text. Use APIs like `OutputStream` and `InputStream` that work with byte arrays.

If you need to store the cipher text as text, encode it with a binary-to-text encoding like Base64.

Specifically, you should replace your write of the cipher text with something like this:

```
try {
  Files.write(Paths.get(cInputFile), cipherText);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println("File Write Error");
  System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, the example was provided by my professor so I'm not sure why it was using the incorrect method.  Doomed from the start haha @erickson

Comment: @erickson is it a good idea to read from the plaintext file before encryption as UTF-8 encoded? and to write the decrypted file as UTF-8 as well or should they be regarded as byte files as well

Comment: @CSjunkie That depends on the encoding used when the plain text file was written; they should match. If you wrote the file yourself, most likely the default encoding on your system was used. On linux, `locale charmap` will tell you that. On Windows I think it's `chcp`.