# AES encryption and decryption data loss

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

When i try to encrypt a MD5 hash of a key using AES ECB,
And afterwards decrypt it i get diffrent results:

**Before**: >•ly†lrœËGQ2¶ª€

**After**: 0¦t‹
d)§¥›B?W

The code i use for Encryption and Decryption is:

```
public class AES {
    private String a= "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
    private byte[] key;
    Cipher c;
    public AES(byte [] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
            this.key = key;
            c = Cipher.getInstance(a);
        }
public String encrypt(byte[] Data) throws Exception{
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] encoded = c.doFinal(Data);
        String encrypted= new String(encoded);
        return encrypted;

    }
public String decrypt(byte[] v) throws Exception{
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        if(v.length%16!=0)
            return null;
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] decv = c.doFinal(v);
        String decrypted = new String(decv);
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: This operation loses information: `String encrypted = new  String(encoded);`. Don't try to encode arbitrary binary data as text like that. Use base64 or hex.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was the line resulting in the loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
String encrypted= new String(encoded);
```

The cipher text bytes in `encoded` are pseudo-random gibberish. It's highly unlikely they form a valid text encoding, regardless of your platform default.

If you need a text representation, use base-64 encoding:

```
String encrypted = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encoded);
```

This is a common mistake, although it manifests in different ways, so the "questions" are varied and hard to identify as duplicates. [Here's another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28705081/3474) with more detail.